# Catan Universe (iPad app) how to regain longest road by filling in a missing piece between 2 roads?

Tags: catan

I’ve got 2 pieces of road with a gap in the middle. I want to fill that gap with a road and get the longest road victory points. The app will not let me do it. Is this a bug or a rule I’m not understanding correctly? See attachment - blue circled area is where I want to put red road to fill the gap.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You have all 15 road pieces in play; the number is strictly limited and once you've built all 15 you can't build any more.

Quoting from [page 4 of the rules](https://www.catan.com/sites/default/files/2021-06/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf):

> You cannot build more pieces than what is available in your pool—a maximum of 5 settlements, 4 cities, and 15 roads.

Comment: I see people run up against the five town limit all the time, as it makes it extremely difficult to win without building any cities, but running out of roads is a bit less common